# use of multiple tags

Tags: discussion, tags

I've seen a question which was tagged `regex` and `virtual-machine` about parsing and evaluating a regular expression with a so-called regular expression virtual machine.

Given that the `virtual-machine` tag is defined as

> A virtual-machine is software emulating complete computer hardware. There are various applications that supply this functionality.

would it be acceptable to use the combination of those tags? or should a `regex-virtual-machine` tag be created?

EDIT

I have found another pair of misused tags: [tree] and [segment] to refer to segment trees.

As in the other pair, one of them is precise, but they are used in conjunction by the poster to refer to a topic which hasn't a specific tag.

Comment: Ugh, don't do that.  [virtual-machine] is already a heavy contextual tag, given that there are so many different kinds around and the VM of, say [java] has nothing to do with [vmware] or [azure].  Just don't do anything.

Comment: I asked because a regex vm is not a software emulating complete hardware. if the use of the virtual-machine tag is not so strict its definition could be relaxed a bit as septi suggested.

Comment: maybe my question was a bit imprecise. I wasn't proposing to merge both tags, but to use a proper tag to replace virtual-machine which in this case would have another meaning with a more specific one.

Answer (score 6):

First, you have to look at the tag problem from the other side: what questions do you expect to get if you click on a tag?

If I click on `virtual-machine`, I obviously expect all kinds of questions related to virtual machines (as defined in the tag description). If I click on `regex`, the questions should of course be related to regex.

Having a combined tag can make the search process far more easier, however, the tag shouldn't be so specific, that it creates an own tiny separated space, which'll probably never reach other persons looking for the topic.

So in this case, I guess the problem is, that a regex virtual machine is kind of a rare thing (<200 Google hits) and the regex experts may overlook them if you tag them with a new category.

**TL;DR**

In my opinion `regex` should still be used and the description of `virtual-machine` should be a bit generalised. Which in fact could solve similar problems with `virtual machine` tags in future ;)

Comment: I agree the scope of virtual machine could be extended. didn't think about it that way.

Comment: Virtualizing machines and creating bytecode interpreters are two different subjects, they should not be in the same tag enough those the later can be known by the same name as the former.